# Навигация по виртуальной консоли в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Не могу найти навигацию по консоли (листание вверх-вниз). Не терминал, а та консоль, которая вызывается **Ctrl-Alt-F#**. **Shift-PageUp/Down** не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Листание страниц `Shift+PgUp/PgDn` работает, пока вы не переключитесь на другую консоль, после переключения история забывается. Помочь может утилита `screen`.

Comment: таки да!========проверила, до переключения у меня запоминает и листает 165 строк. буду пробовать screen. *огромное спасибо за помощь и подсказку!*

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно `Ctrl-Alt`-(стрелку влево, или вправо).

Comment: Спасибо! Только пробовала эту комбинацию - не срабатывает.>если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно...Мне нужно листание страниц. типа стандартного PageUp / PageDown.

Answer (score 0):

```
# chvt 1  1- это номер консоли
```